# Enable WCF calls in a Windows Phone Mango

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, sdk

I developed a WCF in a Managed Windows Service, based on this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

This is how my interface are defined :

```
namespace HomeAutomationWindowsService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHomeAutomation
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string connect();

        [OperationContract]
        Boolean sendAction(string address, string command);
    }
}
```

And my App.config file is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Unsecured">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="HomeAutomationWindowsService.HomeAutomationService"
               behaviorConfiguration="HomeAutomationServiceBehavior">
      <host>
          <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://192.168.11.178:8000/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
      </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by     host: http://localhost:8000/service  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  contract="HomeAutomationWindowsService.IHomeAutomation"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Unsecured" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is explosed at http://192.168.11.178:8000/    mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HomeAutomationServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I make a call from a Console or a WPF App I can see the public methods, but when I do it using Windows Phone I can't see anything.

What I should do to make my WCF or Windows Phone communicating together.

Comment: Have you tried adding service reference ? Check this article: http://eliasmarkelis.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/windows-phone-7-with-wcf/

Comment: Did you add a CrossDomainPolicy file to your service side?

Comment: In Desktop Silverlight you need a file specifying you can access the service. It's called clientaccesspolicy.xml and need to be in the root of domain. Maybe this behavior was inherit to Windows Phone.

Comment: @DmitriyReznik I did it, and I can instantiate the a Service, it's just that I cannot access to the public functions.

Comment: @VitorCanova I found that people who are using Silverlight had the same problem, I'm trying to see what I can get to resolve that problem.

Comment: Take a look this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637518(VS.92).aspx Maybe it can help

Answer (score 0):

I think `WsHttpBinding` is not supported by WP7. Try using `BasicHttpBinding`:

Web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyProject.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding" contract="MyProject.MyService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="binding">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

After adding the webservice to your WP7 project (add service reference) the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` should look like (adding web service with `WsHttpBinding` generates an empty file):

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_DataService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:44300/Services/DataService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_DataService"
                contract="DataService.DataService" name="BasicHttpBinding_DataService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```